# how to save large html content (article) in mongoDB collection field?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, text

I want to save the large html content in mongodb but it doesn't allow to save more than 1 kb of content in single field of collection. 
Basically i am building a article submission web app using NUXT & database i choose is Mongodb. Now i am stuck in this crucial task.

any help would be great!

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ArticleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title : { type : String , unique : true, required : true},
    description: { type : String , unique : true, required : true},
    content: { type : String , unique : true, required : true},
    banner: { type : String },
    active: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    created_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updated_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    postedBy: {
        type : Object , required : true
    },
    comments: [{
        text: String,
        postedBy: {
            type : Object , required : true
        }
    }]
  });
module.exports = mongoose.model('Article', ArticleSchema);
```

Getting this error while saving large content:

```
Btree::insert: key too large to index, failing tech-expert.articles.$content_1 3500 { : \"<p>Here is Sample text!Here is Sample text!Here is Sample text!Here is Sample text!Here is Sample text!Here is Sample text!Here is Sample text!Here is...\" }"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have an index on `content` field. Consider removing this index, or replacing it with [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/)

**UPD:** Mongoose would automatically create Unique index if you schema says `unique: true`  - just get rid of this part for the `content` field. [Mongoose Schema Type](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html)

Comment: seems like removing unique: true is not helping at all.

Comment: Did you just changed the JS code and run it against the same database? If so - index definition your code created earlier might still be there. Try to either drop the index on MongoDB side or just recreate the entire collection.

Comment: I have changed the field name content to

textcontent: { type : String , required : true},

and  added the text index for that

ArticleSchema.index({textcontent: 'text'});

It worked for first time but for next time it returned the error 

E11000 duplicate key error index: tech-expert.articles.$content_1 dup key: { : null }

Comment: Even though you removed it from JavaScript code, your schema on MongoDB side still has a $content field, which is required and unique. Now you just not populating it (it turns to null) and it is failing the uniqness check. If there is no data to salvage I'd suggest just drop the field/index/entire collection in MongoDB or at least use different collection name on JS side.

Comment: Oh, i understand now, thanks Anton for your continues support.